# From arrow function, push object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, arrow-functions

The async/await function `search` returns an object similar to:

```
[
  {
    "title":"page title",
    "url":"/page/url/index.html",
    "content":"blah blah blah"
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to push each object from `val` into the array, but when I push using:

```
results = [];
search(input).then(val=> results.push(val));
```

I get a nested array similar to (I want to the object entries to be top level in the array):

```
[
  [
    {title:"...", url:"...", content:"..."},
    {title:"...", url:"...", content:"..."},
  ]
]
```

So I tried a `for` in the arrow to push each entry in the object into the array, but that didn't seem to work.

```
results = [];
search(input).then(val=> for(i in val) {results.push(val[i])});
```

Comment: Try this: search(input).then(val=> results.push(...val));

Comment: Can't you just use `results = val`? although I don't really see a purpose of doing this as you'll only be able to access the populated version of `results` once your promise has resolved, such as in the `.then()` callback, so you might as well just use `val`

Comment: Try `search(input).then(val=> [].concat(results, val));`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `.push()`, use `.concat()`

```
results = [];
search(input).then(val=> { results = results.concat(val) });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`**

No `For loop` needed either.

```
search(input).then(val=> results = [...results,...val]);
```

or as @Patrick_Hund suggested

```
search(input).then(val=> results.push(...val));
```

here problem is that you are pushing array in to an array.

**You need to push the elements of array.**

**Spreading syntax** should fix the issue.

Hope you have clear understanding now.

Comment: push accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, so you can just use the spread operator on val to push to results: `search(input).then(val=> results.push(...val));`

Comment: you don't need a for loop here

Comment: @PatrickHund - post yours as an answer, and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array and call a function that will return `Promise<array>` you don't need to perform any iteration on the result. **Concat**enate the arrays:

```js
async function getNewData() {
  return Promise.resolve([{
    d: 1
  }, {
    e: 3
  }]);
}

let results = [{
  a: 3
}, {
  b: 4
}];

getNewData().then(newdata => {
  results = results.concat(newdata); 
  // same as results = [...results, ...newdata];

  console.log(results);
});
```

On the other hand, you could also **push**  using the spread operator

```js
async function getNewData() {
  return Promise.resolve([{
    d: 1
  }, {
    e: 3
  }]);
}

const results = [{
  a: 3
}, {
  b: 4
}];

getNewData().then(newdata => {
  results.push(...newdata); 
  // same as results.push(newdata[0], newdata[1], etc)

  console.log(results);
});
```

This approach might be confusing as people tend to ignore the variadic nature of *Array.prototype.push*, **but** it avoids redeclaring `results`, so you may declare the target array as **const**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a for loop, you'll have to do

```
for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++) {
    results.push(val[i])
}
```

There are more succinct ways to do this (see Patrick Hund's comment), but that's how you do it with a for loop.